# What date is assigned to Hippocratic treatises "On Generation" and "On the Nature of the Child"?

Tags: biographical-details, ancient-greece, biology

On the nature of the Child is quoted by Galen in his Book "On Semen". I want to know what date is given to these two books, especially "On Generation"?

Comment: Crops -> Corpus?

Comment: [Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hippocratic_Corpus) states: "*Generation* and *On the Nature of the Child* constitute a single work by a late-fifth-century author", and cites Iain M. Lonie, *The Hippocratic Treatises" On Generation", On the Nature of the Child," Diseases IV"*, de Gruyter 2011. A [review](https://tinyurl.com/2p92v7nn) of this book states: "There are also valuable appendices on the author's date, c. 410 B.C." As this is completely outside my area of expertise, I am posting this comment, not an answer.